# Computing Translation and rotation axis and angle in *Instance entry in Abaqus

Tags: abaqus

Can anyone please help me how the translation and rotation points are computed and written in *INSTANCE entry in Abaqus? I am unable to understand the documentation, it's not elaborate.

I have attached the image : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OFrW.png)

When I translate and rotate the component, it writes the following values, I am unable to figure out how its computed.?

Can anyone help?

Comment: please post the code you have tried, also please do not use images for any code or results unless they are images: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**Rotation**

When you rotate an instance you get a tuple in which has following things:

1)Point of rotation
2)Axis of rotation(direction vector)
3)Rotation angle (in degrees)

Use getRotation() to get these values

you can use these values in rotateAboutAxis(...) api to replicate rotation of one instance on other

**Translation**

When you translate you get a tuple of three Floats: representing translation in the X-, Y-, and Z-directions.

Use getTranslation() to get these values

you can use these values in translate(...) api to replicate translation of one instance on other

Please refer getRotation(), getTranslation(), getPosition(), rotateAboutAxis(...) and translate(...) api in abaqus

*PS: I could't view the image you shared*